# How can I add product to shopify store from another website?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I want add products to Shopify store form another website (maybe) using API. I not finding the request URL for do it. Please help me make it. I Writing this website with PHP (Laravel framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create new product you can use the [Product REST API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07#create-2020-07)

Example:

```
POST /admin/api/2020-07/products.json
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "metafields": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "value": "newvalue",
        "value_type": "string",
        "namespace": "global"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Pay attention that for such type operation you will need to have the [`write_products`](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/access-scopes) scope